# get and evaluate javascript -- why not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page where I load some content from a different page on click. This content needs some extra javascript to work, so I want to also load this and execute it via eval(). This is my approach but it is not working:

```
$.get('jsfile.js', function(jsfile) {
     eval(jsfile);
});
$('#content').load('otherpage.php #thiscontent');
```

I don't understand why it's not working. I know inline javascript normally won't execute, but shouldn't eval() be taking care of that?

Comment: Why not just include the file in HTML? `<script src='jsfile.js'></script>`

Comment: What if any error messages are logged to the console?  What does the string "jsfile" look like before it gets executed?

Comment: $.getScript? http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/

Comment: Try `$('#content').load('otherpage.php #thiscontent', function () {
    $.getScript('jsfile.js')
});`

Comment: @RahulDesai because it's a link that gets rarely clicked on. it's just not necessary for all users to load this huge js file.

Comment: @Kolban it's a normal jquery file. if i open up otherpage.php separately it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is because when you specify a page fragment when calling `jQuery.load`, the script tags are stripped.

See [Loading Page Fragments](https://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments) on the [`jQuery.load`](https://api.jquery.com/load/) documentation.

> The .load() method, unlike $.get(), allows us to specify a portion of
>   the remote document to be inserted. This is achieved with a special
>   syntax for the url parameter. If one or more space characters are
>   included in the string, the portion of the string following the first
>   space is assumed to be a jQuery selector that determines the content
>   to be loaded.

You will need to use another feature to achieve your desired result.